# How do I find ZipArchive extension

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

How do I find ZipArchive extension. I need to add it to my PHP extension in Wamp  server. I've looked all over on google.Everyone tells me what to do when I get the extension. Know one tells me how to get the extension.

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php

Comment: Thank you I've looked in http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php  but I could not fined one for Wamp .